# Как реализовать конвертацию изображений в webp формат

Tags: php, webp

У меня несколько сайтов, на всех практически стоит Wordpress в нем легко, просто установил плагин, а на самописном движке не знаю как это реализовать пока что я считаю, что нужно в папку загрузить скрипт /js/webp.js, а в footer прописать
<cкрипт src="/js/webp.js" ></скрипт >
Help парни

Comment: так посмотрите исходники этого плагина

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagewebp.php

Comment: И как мне его использовать и какой код и куда вставить? В код движка config.ini ?

Comment: я то откуда знаю, куда  в ваш самописный движок надо вставлять конвертацию эту. Где-то вероятно вы должны ресайзить залитые фотки при аплоаде, там же и конвертацию делать. Поскольку поддержка  webp в РФ заявлена для 70% браузеров, то видимо на фронте надо определять, если поддерживается, то грузить такую картинку, если нет, то обычную. Оно вам вообще надо?

Comment: К сожалению, да, потому что гугл считает, что он не оптимизирован для мобильных устройств